# Delete page not showing selected record

Tags: linq, webforms, repository, asp.net-mvc-routing

This is homework, an ASP.NET MVC and Web forms Web application using a repository (with data hard coded and no database) to rate doctors. The user should be able to edit and delete records, but when the application is run, and the "Delete" link is pressed for one of the records, the Delete page does not show the details of that record.  Why not?

[image]

Here are the Delete methods:

```
public ActionResult Delete(string DoctorPicture)
        {
            repo.Remove(DoctorPicture);
            return View("Delete");
        }


[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(string DoctorPicture, FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add delete logic here
            repo.Remove(DoctorPicture);
            return View("Delete");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

From `repo.Remove(DoctorPicture);` it goes here in TestDoctorRepository, and doctor is null.  Is it supposed to be?

```
public void Remove(string DoctorPicture)
        {
            var doctor = from d in doctors where d.DoctorPicture == DoctorPicture select d;
            doctors.Remove(doctor.FirstOrDefault());
        }
```

This is what my list of doctors looks like.  Is my path for the images posing a problem?

```
public TestDoctorRepository()
        {
            doctors = new List<Doctor> {
                new Doctor { DoctorPicture = "Images/0cropped.jpg", DoctorName = "Michael Shores", DoctorSpecialty = "Opthamology", times = 0, rating = 0, rated = true, avg=0, fave = true },
            //more doctors
            };
        }

public Doctor GetDoctorByDoctorPicture(string DoctorPicture)
        {
            var selectedDoctor = from d in doctors
                                 where d.DoctorPicture == DoctorPicture
                                 select d;
            return selectedDoctor.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

Delete View:

```
@model MidtermApplication.Models.Doctor

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}

<h2>Delete</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Doctor</legend>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DoctorPicture)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DoctorPicture)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DoctorName)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DoctorName)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DoctorSpecialty)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DoctorSpecialty)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.rating)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.rating)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.times)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.times)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fave)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.fave)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.rated)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.rated)
    </div>
</fieldset>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
}
```

Comment: You're removing the doctor on both the GET and the POST?  And what does your view look like?

Comment: I added the Delete View to the bottom of the question.